# Execution on Jquery dialog twice in a row not executing properly as expected

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-dialog

I'm trying to create a Jquery dialog which is basically a form that accepts input from the user.

Instead of doing a regular "save & close" dialog, I am trying to do a "save, and do whatever, then close when you like it" dialog, which essentially means the view model being passed to the controller after clicking save the first time, will return, and then allow for further saves.

My dialog code with the save button is like so:

```
$(function () {
        $("#EventDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false, minWidth: 600, minHeight: 360, modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Save": function () {
                    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");

                    if ($("#EventManage").valid()) {
                         $.ajax({
                            url: "/Home/EventSave",
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: $("#EventManage").serialize(),
                            success: function (result) {
                                //alert("s");
                                $("#EventManage").html(result);
                                //$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#EventManage");
                                LoadEventList();

                            }
                        });
```

Clicking on the dialog's save button executes the EventSave action in the controller.

```
public ActionResult EventSave(EventManageModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Event e = new Event();
                    try
                    {
                        //get existing event
                        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(model.EventID))
                        {
                            Guid id = default(Guid);
                            if (Guid.TryParse(model.EventID, out id))
                                e = EventService.GetRecord(id, usr);
                        }

                        e.Name = model.Event_Name;
                        e.Date = DateTime.Parse(model.Event_Date);
                        e.Sender = usr;

                        e = EventService.SaveUpdateEvent(e);

                        //just to update the model with saved data.
                        model.EventID = e.Id.ToString();
                        model.Event_Name = e.Name;
                        model.Event_Date = e.Date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

                        TempData["Message"] = string.Format("Event saved successfully.");
                    }
                    catch (ApplicationException ex)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", ex.Message);
                    }
            }
        }
        return PartialView("EventManage", model);
    }
```

My model has a eventid which tracks down which event is being configured.

```
public class EventManageModel
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public string EventID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Event Name")]
        public string Event_Name { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Event Date [DD/MM/YYYY]")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$", ErrorMessage = ExceptionConstants.ERR_DATE_INVALID)]
        public string Event_Date { get; set; }
    }
```

At the moment, when I click save the first time, the model passed into the action in the controller is valid, with full valid data. the returned view is loaded as per above dialog's button execution. however saving it the second time the model being passed in is null.

Is this behavior supposed to be like that? Or is there something wrong with my code somewhere?

**EDIT**

After post, i run firebug and it seems to show this error when I click on any of the textboxes in the dialog (which I don't know what would it mean)

f is undefined
[Break On This Error] "");f.settings[g]&&f.settings[g].call(.../\s/),function(g,h){b[h]=e})});var d=

jquery....min.js (line 22)

Any idea?